# Is there a way to do a "not adjacent to" selector, opposite of the + operator

Tags: css, css-selectors

In css, can select an element that follows an element using the `+` operator. For example, I can select only inputs that directly follow labels by doing:

```
label + input {
    color: red;
}
```

Is there a way to do the opposite, so like "not adjacent to"? In my example, is there a way to select all inputs that *do not* directly follow labels?

Edit:
It needs to select ALL inputs that don't directly follow labels, including inputs that are in places with no labels whatsoever.

Comment: `label + input ~ input {}` uses the general sibling selector to do what you want. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/nbrwh7ge/

Comment: The problem with that is that there has to be an initial label present in order for it to work.

Comment: Yeah, it was based on your original question before you edited it to add the additional requirement.

Comment: @Pete Apologies, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it would be

```css
input:first-child, :not(label) + input {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
input {
  background: red;
}
input:first-child, :not(label) + input {
  background: #0f0;
}
body > * {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input value="Match (first child)" />
<label>&lt;label&gt;</label>
<span>&lt;span&gt;</span>
<input value="Match (immediately follows a non-label)" />
<label>&lt;label&gt;</label>
<input value="NO match (immediately follows a label)" />
<span>&lt;span&gt;</span>
```

Answer (score 9):

Like this

```
:not(label) + input {
    color: red;
}
```

... well, if you will have an input direct after the body tag you need Oriol's additional selector `input:first-child`