# CSS rule to match element not followed by another element of specific class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766532/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-not-adjacent-to-selector-opposite-of-the-operator), but not identical to it...

In my case I have the following layout:

```
<span class="title">Title1:</span>
<span class="content">Content1</span>
<span class="title">Title2:</span>
<span class="content">Content2</span>
<span class="title">Title3:</span>
<span class="content">Content3</span>
<span class="title">Title4:</span>
<span class="content">Content4</span>
```

Which is displayed like this:

**Title1:** Content1

**Title2:** Content2

**Title3:** Content3

**Title4:** Content4

with the help of the following CSS

```
span.title{
    font-weight: bold;
}

span.content::after {
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

However, there will be a case where the **first** `span.title` will be *orphan* - not followed by a `span.content` but rather by another `span.title`. In that special case, I want the orphan `span.title` to be in its own line... So it will be like this:

**Oprhan title**

**Title1:** Content1

**Title2:** Content2

**Title3:** Content3

**Title4:** Content4

What's the correct rule to cover that :not() case?

I've tried quite many variations like the one below, but non seems to work...

```
span.title::after + :not(span.content) {
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: Basically, the more I think about this, the more I suspect it can't be solved in CSS... `+` operator selects the element after it, not before it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could add the line break before the next line instead of after the orphaned title perhaps.

```css
span.title{
    font-weight: bold;
}

span.content::after {
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}

span.title + :not(span.content)::before {
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<span class="title">Orphan Title</span>
<span class="title">Title1:</span>
<span class="content">Content1</span>
<span class="title">Title2:</span>
<span class="content">Content2</span>
<span class="title">Title3:</span>
<span class="content">Content3</span>
<span class="title">Orphan Title2</span>
<span class="title">Orphan Title3</span>
<span class="title">Title1:</span>
<span class="content">Content1</span>
<span class="title">Title2:</span>
<span class="content">Content2</span>
<span class="title">Title3:</span>
<span class="content">Content3</span>
```

Comment: And a very sly/brilliant approach also!!! Instead of adding the newline _after_ the orphan `span.title`, you add it _before_ the `span.title` that follows another (effectively orphan `span.title`)!!! I so much love such clever approaches!!!